# How do I correct a message box error and code a numeric up down?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project in Visual Studio for school and can't figure a few things out. I am new to programming and have been working on this for weeks but keep running into errors.

1. Orders over $300 will display a message box with an error stating manager approval needed. (I have this part). The manager will have to enter the word APPROVED in the txtName field to approve the order, this is the part that's not working.

I have to include a numeric up and down for massage minutes at $3/min up to 90 min this will be added to the total. I can't get this to work at all.

orders still going through after message box with error pops up.

My error messages are working but as soon as I hit OK to acknowledge the error the order displays anyway.

```
Dim strName As String = ""
Dim decTotalCost As Decimal = 0D
Dim decSkinCareCost As Decimal = 0D
Dim decNailCareCost As Decimal = 0D
Dim decWaxingCost As Decimal = 0D

Const FACIAL_PRICE As Decimal = 90D
Const MICRO_PRICE As Decimal = 120D
Const CHEM_PEEL_PRICE As Decimal = 130D
Const MANI_PRICE As Decimal = 25D
Const PEDI_PRICE As Decimal = 55D 
Const MANI_PEDI_PRICE As Decimal = 75D
Const EYEBROW_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 20D
Const LIP_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 15D
Const CHIN_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 15D 
Const JAW_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 20D
Const ARM_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 45D
Const UNDER_ARM_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 20D
Const FEET_HANDS_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 15D
Const LEG_WAX_PRICE As Decimal = 65D
Const NONE_FACE As Decimal = 0D
Const NONE_NAILS As Decimal = 0D

Const strNO_SERVICES_SELECTED_ERROR As String = "ERROR: Please select a 
service."
Const strORDER_OVER_300_ERROR As String = "ERROR: Order over $300, please 
see manager for approval"
Const strNO_NAME_ERROR As String = "ERROR:  Please enter a name."

Dim strNoNameMessage As String = strNO_NAME_ERROR
Dim strManagerApproval As String = strORDER_OVER_300_ERROR
Dim strNoServicesSelected As String = strNO_SERVICES_SELECTED_ERROR

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnSubmit.Click
    If txtName.Text <> "" Then
        If radFacial.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + FACIAL_PRICE
        ElseIf radMicro.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + MICRO_PRICE
        ElseIf radChemPeel.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + CHEM_PEEL_PRICE
        ElseIf radNoneFace.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = NONE_FACE
        End If
        If radMani.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + MANI_PRICE
        ElseIf radPedi.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + PEDI_PRICE
        ElseIf radManiPedi.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + MANI_PEDI_PRICE
        ElseIf radNoneNails.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = NONE_NAILS
        End If
        If chkEyebrow.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + EYEBROW_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkLip.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + LIP_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkChin.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + CHIN_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkJaw.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + JAW_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkArm.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + ARM_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkUnderArm.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + UNDER_ARM_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkFeetHands.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + FEET_HANDS_WAX_PRICE
        End If
        If chkLeg.Checked = True Then
            decTotalCost = decTotalCost + LEG_WAX_PRICE
        End If

        If decTotalCost > 300D Then
            MsgBox(strORDER_OVER_300_ERROR)
            txtName.Focus()
        ElseIf decTotalCost = 0D Then
            MsgBox(strNO_SERVICES_SELECTED_ERROR)
        End If

        MsgBox("Thank you, " & txtName.Text & " Your Spa total is: " & 
        decTotalCost.ToString("C"))
    Else
        txtName.Text = ""
        MsgBox(strNO_NAME_ERROR)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
```

Comment: A message box, on its own, doesn't do anything magical; it simply displays a message to the user, that's it. You need to handle the logic of preventing the code from continuing. For example, you would call `Exit Sub` after `MsgBox(strORDER_OVER_300_ERROR) : txtName.Focus()`. On another note, when posting a question with a problem in the code, you only need to include the relevant parts of your code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Questions must relate to a specific issue, so a question asking for help with the `TextBox` and the `NumericUpDown` are invalid.  Please edit your question to focus on one specific issue.  Also, have you actually debugged your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through it line by line? If not, you need to do that before posting here. If so, please describe EXACTLY where and how the observed behaviour differs from your expectations.

Comment: Adding to jmchihinney's comment. For debugging, run your code using the `F8` key (windows). This allows you to step through the code line by line. Holding the mouse over variables will display their value, and you will be able to see what exactly is happening in your code. Hopefully this will help you to fix your problem.